# Pagination not initializing on page refresh with multiple sliders throughout the page-slick library

Tags: javascript, jquery

The pagination value is not initialized when I refresh the page. Works only once I click on next or previous button.

```
var $slickElement = $('.paragraph-slider, .gallery-slider');
$slickElement.each(function() {
    if($(this).find('.pagination').length < 1) {
        $(".gallery-slider").append('<div class="pagination"></div>');
    }
    $(this).once().on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // CurrentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based).
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        // $value = $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
        $(this).find('.pagination').html(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you get some error?

Comment: No didn't get any error.

Comment: And how we can help ypu if you didn't provide more details?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve here is to initialise the value on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it...incase anyone stumbles across this.All you need is a window onload function to initialize the pagination value.You can add this to the above code.

```
        $slickElement.each(function(){
          var count = $(this).find(".slick-slide").length;
          $(this).find('.pagination').html(1 + '/' + count);
        });
      }

      // Window onload call addPagination function.
      $(window).on('load', function(){
        addPagination();
      });
```